# How to convert raw data to excel file in django

Tags: django, django-testing

In one of my application test case, I have to open the email attachment file and verify the data it is an excel file. The email attachment what I get in the test is like this `

\xd0\xcf\x11\xe0\xa1\xb1\x1a\xe1\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x03\x00\xfe\xff\t\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\xfe\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfe\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x

How to convert it back to excel file.`

Here is my test code

```
    def test_for_attachments(self):
       self.response = self.client.post(reverse('batches:detail_excel', kwargs={'batch_id': self.batch.id}))
       attachments = mail.outbox[0].attachments
       self.assertEqual(attachments[0][0],'success-report.xls')
       self.assertEqual(attachments[0][2],'application/vnd.ms-excel')
       self.assertContains(attachments[0][1],self.user.username)
```

attachments[0][1] is the content file.

Comment: What have you attempted? What does your test code look like?

Comment: Edited please check.

Comment: try creating file in write-binary and write the data into it